# `react-native run-ios` opens two debug tabs with error

Tags: ios, google-chrome, debugging, react-native, ios-simulator

I'm building an app with **react-native** for a few months already. Lately, when I start simulator with 'react-native run-ios' *two* tabs of **debugger-ui** are opened in a Chrome browser simultaneously and **simulator** gives error on `Connection to http://localhost:8081/debugger-proxy?...`.
Closing one tab of **debugger-ui** and refreshing another one, plus **simulator**, solves the problem, but I want to figure out the reason why this is happening and solve it completely.

I think that has to do something with **simulator** rather than **react-native** itself. Any ideas where to look for solving this issue and why it occurs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've also encountered this problem recently.

Comment: Still happens from time-to-time, can't figure out the real reason yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way I found to solve this problem is to RESET simulator completely.

Go to `Simulator` and click on `Reset Content and Settings...`.